# Using a mobile browser, can I store formular-data offline in the cache/localStorage and submit it later when there is internet connection?

Tags: html, forms, caching, mobile-browser

Like Stackoverflow is cached and displayed even if I don't have any internet connection, I want to use a formular which can be hold in the cache.

Next I want the user to be able to enter data, "upload" a picture even if there is no internet connection.

All the submitted data shall be transferred to a server when the  mobile phone gets internet connection again automatically or triggered on a sync button.

As I super plus point the user should be able to repeat the task of submitting data more then only one time.

If there is such a solution, I am also interested in the limits of it. How big is the cache/localStorage, does it work for android, ios and Microsoft?
Are there any methods to measure and display the cache/localStorage status?

Links, Examples, Libraries, Experiences appreciated!

Comment: Not the cache, but you can use **localStorage**. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).) I don't have enough experience with it to provide a real answer though.

Comment: :) thanks Mr. Lister. I can expand my research on that ... I was thinking about that app-cache things ... but that would also be a good way.